# Least and greatest possible values of perimeter of a triangle.

Tags: trigonometry

One side of a triangle is 5 cm and the other side is10 cm and its perimeter is P cm , where P is an integer. The least and the greatest possible values of P are respectively

1. 21 and 29
2. 22 and 27
3. 19 and 29
4. 20 and 28

I have no idea how to approach this question. Please help me.

Answer (score 3):

Imagine two strips of paper, one $5$ cm long, the other $10$. Join them at one end. Now vary the angle between them to construct all the possible triangles with those two sides. When will the third side be shortest? When longest?

Answer (score 2):

sum of 2 sides in a triangle is more than the third side.

If 10 the largest side then the third side should be at least 6. Therefore the minimum value of p is 5+6+10=21.

If the third side is the largest then it should be less than 15 i.e. greatest possible value of the third side is 14. Therefore the maximum possible value of p is 15+14=29.

Answer (score 1):

Given the sides $5, 10, x$ and the perimeter $P=5+10+x=15+x$, use the [triangle inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality):
$$\begin{cases}5+10>x \\ 5+x>10\\ 10+x>5\end{cases} \Rightarrow \\
5<x<15 \Rightarrow \\
5+15<x+15<15+15 \Rightarrow \\
20<P<30 $$ 
The sides are integer, so, can you find the smallest and largest values of $P$?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the vertices of the triangle in the complex plane. Let the common point for the line segments with length $5$ and $10$ be $O$. Without loss of generality, assume $O$ to be the origin of the complex plane. So, you may assume that the other ends of the line segments with length $5$ and $10$ be $A$ and $B$ respectively. Suppose that $a$ and $b$ be complex numbers that corresponds to the vertices $A$ and $B$ respectively. Therefore, $|a|=5$ and $|b|=10$ and the length $AB=|a-b|$.Therefore the perimeter $P=|a|+|b|+|a-b|$. Clearly, the following inequality holds
$$|a|+|b|\geq |a-b|\geq ||a|-|b||$$and hence we get,$$2(|a|+|b|)\geq P\geq |a|+|b|+||a|-|b||$$and using the fact $2|a|=|b|=10$ we get $P\in(20,30)$. But since $P\in\mathbb{Z}$, we can say that $P\in[21,29]$.